# Header redirects BEFORE page is loaded, but still runs SQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I'm trying to allow people who have signed up to my site to be able to change their passwords by going to 'change-password.php?pid=(their unique id)'. Here's the code:

```
<?php
    // Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
    if ($_POST["newpw"] == $_POST["confirmpw"]) {
        $pid = $_SESSION["pid"];
        $newpw = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['confirmpw']);
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET password='$newpw' WHERE pid='$pid'");
        $confirmation = "Thank You; your password has now been changed.";
        echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('$confirmation')
            window.location.href='playerparent-profile.php?pid=$pid';
        </SCRIPT>";
        exit();
    } else {
        header("location: change-password.php?pid=$pid"); 
    }
?>
```

The problem I have is, before the page even loads up, it acts as though a new password has been given, so it gives the alert immediately and takes them back to their profile page. It's running the SQL because the password in the database becomes blank, but what is causing the page NOT to load?

Here's the HTML for the password fields:

```
             <form onSubmit="return validate()" action="change-password.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
              <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu20726"><!-- group -->
               <div class="grpelem" id="u20726"><!-- simple frame --></div>
               <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u20724"><!-- group -->
                <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u20725-4"><!-- content -->
                 <p>CHANGE PASSWORD</p>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu20727-4"><!-- group -->
               <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u20727-4"><!-- content -->
                <p>OLD PASSWORD:</p>
               </div>
               <div class="grpelem"><input type="text" required id="u20729" name="oldpw" title="Fill in your old password. This field is required" class="form-element form-element-medium text-element"  /><!-- simple frame --></div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu20728-4"><!-- group -->
               <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u20728-4"><!-- content -->
                <p>NEW PASSWORD:</p>
               </div>
               <div class="grpelem" ><input type="password" required id="u20730" name="newpw" title="Fill in your old password. This field is required" class="form-element form-element-medium text-element"  /><!-- simple frame --></div>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix colelem" id="pu20733-4"><!-- group -->
               <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u20733-4"><!-- content -->
                <p>CONFIRM NEW PASSWORD:</p>
               </div>
               <div class="grpelem"><input type="password" required id="u20735" name="confirmpw" title="Fill in your old password. This field is required" class="form-element form-element-medium text-element"  /><!-- simple frame --></div>
              </div>
              <div class="colelem" id="u20737"><!-- simple frame --></div>
             </div>
             <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u20738"><!-- group -->
              <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u20739-4"><!-- content -->
               <p><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">Change Password</a><p>
             </form>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please tell me you're not storing passwords in plaintext in your database.

Comment: Add a **name** to your `<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">Change Password</a>` and in your php code `if ($_POST['Namea'])` aroud ALL your php code

Comment: always put `die();` after a redirect header like that stop further execution of the page.

Comment: @Hearner, I see the logic behind this, but surely this is the same as me having it as $_POST['newpw']?

Comment: No because in your code, if there is no `$_POST['newpw']` it goes to the  `else` that redirect. So if you don't want it to be executed on loading you have to put a condition (if) on it

Comment: @Dave thanks for the tip, I've added it to the end now.

Comment: @Hearner ah, I see what you mean now! Worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <form onSubmit="return validate()" action="change-password.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
     <!-- Your code -->
    <p><a href="#" name="test" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">Change Password</a><p>
</form>
```

Add a name to your `<a>`

```
               <?php

            // Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
        if ($_POST['test'])
        {
            if ($_POST["newpw"] == $_POST["confirmpw"]) {
                $pid = $_SESSION["pid"];
                $newpw = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['confirmpw']);
                $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET password='$newpw' WHERE pid='$pid'");
                $confirmation = "Thank You; your password has now been changed.";
            echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('$confirmation')
                window.location.href='playerparent-profile.php?pid=$pid';
                </SCRIPT>";
                exit();
            } else {
                    header("location: change-password.php?pid=$pid"); 
            }
        }
            ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Hearner, as I mentioned under your comment, this worked perfectly!

Comment: Hey.. I know the actualy question has been answered (thanks again), but now the page keeps coming back to change-password, as thought the newpw and confirmpw are wrong?

Comment: You code redirects to `change-password.php?pid=$pid` if `$_POST["newpw"] != $_POST["confirmpw"]`. This is your code. I don't know why you're doing this

Comment: What you want to achieve ? If the passwords don't match what should it do ?

Comment: I just noticed something, what `validate()` does ? Because you can easily do it using JavaScript. Like `function validate()` where you check if the fields match, then return true is they match, or false

Comment: I thought that having the redirect for changepw after else would mean it only redirects if the newpw and confirmpw don't match? I wanted it to run the alert if they =. and run the else if they don't.

Validate is to check if the new and confirmed passwords match, if they don't the page shouldn't run the sql, etc

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `$_POST["newpw"] == $_POST["confirmpw"]` when they are not defined, so add :

```
if((isset($_POST["newpw"]) && isset($_POST["confirmpw"]))&&  $_POST["newpw"] == $_POST["confirmpw"])
```

Comment: Thanks for this Alexis, it didn't work though. I get this error: 

"This webpage has a redirect loop

The webpage at http://sda.dx.am/change-password.php?pid= has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer."